# Which visa should I apply for?

Tags: visa, germany, internship

So, I have two offers in Germany. The first one is a paid research internship for two and a half months (starts in June, 2024) and the second one is a self-financed  research stay for 9 months (starts in  mid August, 2024). What should I do in aspects of applying for a visa? Is it multiple visa? Is there any way to get a single visa? How will it change the Hosting agreement document (provided by german federal government)? Will I require to write any cover letter?